# How to create pie chart using python ?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am conducting an automated test suite using python, I want the console result to shown in form of pie chart, i wanted pass and fails to be in chart, pass in green and fail in red, is there any way in  which i can create pie chart from console result?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html

Comment: Found in 5 seconds with google query!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#change these 2 variables to suit your needs
nPass = 5857 
nFail = 1362

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22}) #adjust font size; not really needed

plt.pie([nPass, nFail],
        colors=["green","red"],
        labels=["Pass", "Fail"],
        autopct='%1.1f%%', 
        startangle=90)

plt.axis('equal') #ensure pie is round
plt.show()
```

Comment: i am getting this error while importin "from pylab import *"

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six

Answer (score 2):

[You can use `matplotlib`/`pylab`](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html):

```
from pylab import *

# make a square figure and axes
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Pass', 'Fail'
fracs = [75, 25]
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)

title('Pass/Fail', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

show()
```